# Anyone get sound working on a HP 8540p?

Tags: 11.04, sound, drivers

When running 10.10 on my HP 8450p laptop, sound worked fine.  I've followed the various instructions on the main Ubuntu site for [DebuggingSoundProblems](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingSoundProblems), but nothing yet.

The hardware buttons on the laptop trigger volume up/volume down, and even mute/unmute.  Yet, the indicator light on the laptop alwayss remain orange (which indicates that the sound is muted).

Comment: Can you link to the instructions you followed or describe your steps briefly?

Comment: Have you tried running `alsamixer` from a terminal session and seeing if any of the sliders there are muted? (MM instead of a number at the bottom of a control)

Comment: @djeikyb I've added a link to the DebuggingSoundProblems page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally got it.  Under the "Sound" application, on the "Hardware" tab, I had to select "Analog Stereo Output" for "Profile".  It was defaulted to "Analog Stereo Duplex".

Answer (score 0):

I found a guy who has the same problem. Check his blog. [Here](http://pario.no/2011/04/10/enable-wireless-in-ubuntu-11-04-beta1-on-a-hp-8540p/) Hope that help.

Comment: That blog entry has to do with the wireless interface, not audio.